# How to avoid Spring cloud config loading property from classpath?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud

I am using the latest version of spring boot and Spring cloud config. When I start my application with application.properties, it works fine as expected.
 But, when I start with bootstrap.yml file, it downloads all the props from Spring cloud and also loads application.properties from classpath. Is that how Spring cloud works? Is it possible to configure Spring cloud config client to read property only from the remote Cloud config and not from application.properties in the class path.

Am using,

> --spring.cloud.bootstrap.location=bootstrap.yaml

But, still appliaction.proerties in the classpath from some jar file is also getting loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! It works like that. If you have both `bootstrap.yml` & `application.yml`. Initially it will load the `bootstrap.yml` properties if you have specified any config server properties then it fetch those properties from config-server.

Once it fetched from config-server then it will load properties from `application.yml`. If you have same key structure in both of yml files then it will be overridden by  `application.yml` properties.

If you dont want value to be overridden then make sure you have different key in both yml files.

Comment: The property file is coming from a 3rd party jar whcih I have included in my pom. Is there any way to ignore them?

Comment: Then you can't have control in it. So better change the key in config-server properties file